# npm install failing after npm upgrade

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a barebone react project. I upgraded all packages to the latest versions since it's a new project. But npm install is failing.

```
garg1@TVQRL MINGW64 /d/coding/github/erodov/app
$ npm i -g npm-check-updates
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

added 288 packages, and audited 289 packages in 19s

55 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

garg1@TVQRL MINGW64 /d/coding/github/erodov/app
$ ncu -u
Upgrading D:\coding\github\erodov\app\package.json
[====================] 12/12 100%

 @testing-library/jest-dom         ^5.11.5  →  ^5.16.4
 @testing-library/react            ^11.1.0  →  ^13.3.0
 @testing-library/user-event      ^12.1.10  →  ^14.2.1
 bootstrap                    ^5.0.0-beta2  →   ^5.1.3
 react                             ^17.0.1  →  ^18.2.0
 react-dom                         ^17.0.1  →  ^18.2.0
 react-router-dom                   ^5.2.0  →   ^6.3.0
 react-scripts                       4.0.0  →    5.0.1
 web-vitals                         ^0.2.4  →   ^2.1.4

Run npm install to install new versions.


garg1@TVQRL MINGW64 /d/coding/github/erodov/app
$ npm i
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: frontend2@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: @testing-library/react@11.2.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!   @testing-library/react@"^13.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @testing-library/react@"^13.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.3.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^13.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\garg1\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\garg1\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-02T20_59_18_305Z-debug-0.log
```

As suggested in error logs is running `npm i --force` or `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` harmless ?

PS: I deleted the package-lock.json file before installing

Comment: What's unclear from the error message? Did you try the things it suggests? Research the problem at all?

Comment: yes, exactly didn't get what's going wrong. Few have suggested it's with the newer version of node. I can choose to just create a new project.

Comment: are these harmless, I can choose to ignore them? by using `npm i --legacy-peer-dependecy`. I am trying to understand why it's giving this error message because  just a few weeks the install was working fine. I had React 17 at that time so dependency should still be a issue

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the `node_modules` folder and did install again this time it worked.